# should I create threads before hand to save time?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 .I am using multi-threading.Now if a thread dies I again
create one to compensate for it.So should I create a lot of threads before hand and store them
and use from them when one or more existing threads die or should I create one when some thread dies??
Which is more efficient in terms of time ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say a thread "dies", do you mean you intentionally terminate it or it fails due to error?

If you're intentionally terminating it and you're worried about the time required to spawn a new thread, why not keep the thread persistent and simply have it do the job that the new thread would have done? This is a pretty standard approach - maintain a pool of "worker" threads and have a work queue with pending items to execute. They all run an identical loop which is to pull an item off the queue and execute it. These items can be objects with methods which contain the code to execute if it's convenient to work that way - if the tasks are all very similar then it might be easier to put the code into the thread's own function instead.

If you're talking about threads failing due to error, I wouldn't have imagined this was common enough to worry about it. If it is, you probably need to look at making your code more robust.

In either case, spawning a thread on most systems should be a lightweight activity - a lot more lightweight than spawning a whole new process, for example. As a result, I really wouldn't worry about keeping a pool of threads in reserve to use - that really sounds like early optimisation to me.

Even if spawning threads were slow, consider what you would be doing by spawning threads in advance - you would be taking up more memory (some memory in the OS to keep track of a the thread, some in Python for the objects that it uses to track the thread), although not a great deal; you'd also be spending more time at the start of your program creating all these threads. So, you might save a little time while you were running, but instead your program takes significantly longer to start. That doesn't sound like a sensible trade-off to me unless the speed and latency of your code is absolutely critical while it's running, and if speed is that critical then I'm not sure a pure Python solution is the right approach anyway. Something like C/C++ is going to give you better control of scheduling, at the expense of much more complexity.

In summary: seriously, don't worry about it, just spawn threads as you need them. Trust me, there will be much bigger speed problems elsewhere in your code which are much more deserving of your time.

Comment: @No it dies due to some exception on its own idon't kill it

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. You know you can always catch exceptions, right? So you could have an outer loop which, say, takes work items off a queue and calls them inside a `try...except` block. If this is a long-running daemon then you could log the exception (always use logging with long-running daemons!) and then carry on with the next item. Even if you don't want to handle the exceptions (it's a matter of preference) I'd still really recommend at least catching, logging and re-raising them. There are few things more annoying to debug than a daemon that doesn't log. (^_^)